# How to set y axis format and remove y axis border line of columnchart package in google api chart?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-api, google-visualization

I am using google api chart in column chart package created to chart. but in this chart cannot be remove y axis line and cannot be set y axis format.

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["columnchart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
          ['2004',  1000,      400],
          ['2005',  1170,      460],
          ['2006',  660,       1120],
          ['2007',  1030,      540]
        ]);

        var options = {
            width: 400, 
            height: 240, 
            legend: 'none',
            bar: { groupWidth: '50%' }

        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this google api chart using columnchart package. column chart package is one of the oldest package, in this package there is no more customization. so we are not set y axis format and remove y axis border line.

> google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:['columnchart']});

the newest version of google api chart package is core chart package. that is

> google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['corechart']});

suppose we are using this package. possible for y axis format and remove y axis border line.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use the `'columnchart'` package - it is old and deprecated.  Use the newer `'corechart'` package instead:

```
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['corechart']});
```

That enables the options you need to format your chart the way you want it.  See the complete list of options [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart#Configuration_Options).  By default, with the `'corechart'` package, there will not be a line on the y-axis in your sample code.  You can format the axis values using the vAxis.format option:

```
vAxis: {
    format: '$#,###'
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I know that columnchart is old version. but corechart package cannot be remove space between two bars. So that i am using columnchart package.

Comment: The gap exists in the "columnchart" package's ColumnCharts as well.

Comment: but i workout corechart package and columnchart package.In corechart package bar gap is appear. Columnchart package bar gap isn't appear.

Comment: The gaps are there when the chart is viewed in Chrome.  The old ColumnCharts do not support axis formatting or the `bar` option, so you can either have the options you want or you can use the old package.

Comment: thanks. In corechart package columnchart how to remove space between two bars?

Comment: set bar.groupWidth to '100%'

Answer (score 0):

```
    function drawVisualization() {
          // Create and populate the data table.
          var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['x', 'Report'],
            ['2013-12-20 10:20:30',   1],
            ['2013-12-20 10:30:30',   2],
            ['2013-12-20 12:20:30',   4],
            ['2013-12-21 10:20:30',   5],
            ['2013-12-21 20:20:30',   2],
            ['2013-12-22 20:20:30',   2],

          ]);

          // Create and draw the visualization.
          new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
              draw(data, {
                          width: 500, height: 400,
                         vAxis: {title: "Health Chart",ticks: [{v:5, f:"Healthy"},{v:2, f:"Unhealthy"},{v:4, f:"Better"},{v:1, f:"Not Good"}]},}
                  );
        }
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);

  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
```

You can run this code on google code playground (ie https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#line_chart)
And change vAxis according to your options.